# Node Property key relations Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have somewhat of a noob question. Im trying to create relations between node property keys, but can't seem to to get my query right.

The node contains two keys: source and destination.

```
{
  "dst": "192.168.XX.XX",
  "src": "192.168.XX.XX"
}
```

I need to create a graph where the scr -> dst.

```
MATCH (n:IOC)
RETURN (n)-[*]->(n);
```

But is not working, any pointers tips or tricks appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to create relations between the same node when the properties `dst` and `src` are the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understood your question completely, but I think you are trying to create a relationship between `n1` and `n2` when `n1.src = n2.dst`. You can do it using:

```
MATCH (n1:IOC), (n2:IOC)
WHERE n1.src = n2.dst
CREATE (n1)-[:RELATIONSHIP_TYPE]->(n2)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to do :) Thanks, works like a charm.

Comment: I guess that this can be done smarter in the CSV import?

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'ip.csv' AS line
CREATE (:IOC { src: line["Source IP"], dst: line["Destination IP"]})

Comment: @Jmik the `LOAD CSV` script in your comment in creating a node with `src` and `dst` properties, not relations between nodes.

Comment: Again Im new to Neo4J :) 
So, what would be the correct what to add the relations, when importing the CSV?

Comment: @Jmik Right! :) In this case, you should execute 2 steps: 1) import your data using the script in your comment and 2) after it, execute the script in my answer. It's not possible do all the work in only one script.

Comment: Ok, makes sense :) Thanks.
Been playing around with this:
`code`MATCH (n1:IOC), (n2:IOC)
WHERE n1.src = n2.dst
CREATE (n1)-[:RELATIONSHIP_TYPE]->(n2)`code`
And it's not quite the output I'm looking for.
src is not always = dst. Basically I only need a visual representation of src->dst